# Filling factors and implementation for non-Abelian models

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, topological-field-theory, anyons

Currently reading through Pachos' Introduction to Topological Quantum Computation, and perusing other related articles and papers online. Have seen in many places that the 5/2 filling factor for quantum fractional Hall effect is the most promising to be experimentally realized (if I'm correct in stating that it has not yet been? Know this is a very fast moving field). However these anyons belong to the Ising model, which isn't universal. We need a filling factor such as 12/5 to implement the Fibonacci model, which is universal.

My question is - why can't we implement Fibonacci with 5/2? What are the requirements needed to implement a given model with a particular anyon?

Comment: The question is whether the actual ground state at 12/5 filling is in the right topological phase, so the excitations are described by the Fibonacci anyon model. This is still not completely settled.

Comment: What exactly is meant by the 'right' topological phase?

Comment: The point is that the topological properties (e.g. fusion, braiding, ...) of low-energy excitations are determined by the ground state, or which "phase" it is in. So to get certain anyon model, the ground state has to be in a particular phase (or "topological order"). The ground state of 5/2 is believed to be a Moore-Read state (or one of its variants), which supports Ising anyons. The "right" ground state for 12/5 that will give you Fibonacci is the $k=3$ Read-Rezayi state.

Answer (score 0):

The anyons for a fixed FQH state have fixed braiding and fusion properties so you cannot change the $v = \frac{5}{2}$ state from Ising to Fibonacci. In general for abelian FQH systems you can fix the anyon properties by fixing the K-matrix and s-vector up to some unitary transforms (sort of). Look at the review article [Topological orders and Edge excitations in FQH states](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9506066) by Xiao-Gang Wen for more details on this.